# argument error c#

Tags: c#

I'm doing an example from the book: The Complete Reference C# 3.0 by Herbert Schildt. It's about writing in Console.WriteLine with arguments. Here is the example: 
I tried this but I was getting an error:

```
Project1.exe has encountered a problem and needs to be close. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please tell Microsoft about this problem. Send Error Report or Don't Send. And if I click, I get another error in the command prompt. "Unhandled Exception: System.Format.Exception input string was not in a correct format. 
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatError()
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider,String Format, Object[]args)
at  System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
at  System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
At Example2.Main() in D:\myPath
```

I'm not sure if the book has some error or is it my code? 
I would appreciate your help. Thanks

> One of the easiest ways to specify a
>   format is to describe a template that
>   WriteLine( ) will use. To do this,
>   show an example of the format that you
>   want, using #s to mark the digit
>   positions. You can also specify the
>   decimal point and commas. For example,
>   here is a better way to display 10
>   divided by 3:
>   Console.WriteLine("Here is 10/3: {0:#.##}", 10.0/3.0);
>     The output from this statement is shown here: Here is 10/3: 3.33

Btw this is my code looks like:

```
   static void Main()
    { 
   Console.WriteLine("Here is 10/3: {0:#.##)", 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong ending brace for the format parameter.

Note the end parenthesis ) after #.##, it should be a } instead (curly braces).

Also note that you have left out the division, and if you simply change your code to this (corrected the brace as well):

```
static void Main()
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Here is 10/3: {0:#.##}", 10/3);
}
```

Then you're going to have another question as well, since the result of that will be:

```
Here is 10/3: 3.00
```

The reason for this is that 10/3 is integer division, see how many times 3 goes up completely in 10, which is 3 times.

If you want floating point division, divide 10 by 3 to get 3 and 1/3rd, then you need to make sure at least one of the numbers are floating point, hence 10.0/3 will do.

Comment: Hi Lasse V. Karlsen, thanks I got it now. yes it was the curly braces. That was quite simple. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong.  You used a parenthesis instead of a curly brace in your string literal.  Try this:

```
static void Main()
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("Here is 10/3: {0:#.##}", 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `)` to `}` - just a typo, it seems.

Comment: Thanks Noldorin, I got it. I'll changed it now;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is wrong. You have a `{` paired with a `)`

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
Console.WriteLine("Here is 10/3: {0:#.##}", 10);
```

When you are using a format you should put it in { and }

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code below:

```
static void Main()    
{    
Console.WriteLine("Here is 10/3: {0:#.##}", 10.0/3);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the end of your string you have a ) instead of a }

Answer (score 0):

Let me also post an identical answer to everybody else for no reason whatsoever!

Replace the ##) with ##} in your code.

Answer (score -1):

That's because **your** code is incorrect.

In more than 1 place!

(the brace and the missing '/3.0' part)